# save html page with the images,javascript and css in one folder in iphone application

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, save, nsurl

I want to save webpage in document directory with the images,css and javascripts etc..

I have done below code : But it only generates the html file..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Any idea or suggestion is most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ASIHTTPRequest project](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) has a class called `ASIWebPageRequest` which is designed to do exactly what you want. If you're okay with adding an additional dependency to your project then I think it's a good solution for you: [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest).

On the page I liked above there are some good examples of how to use it but I'll include one of them here for completeness:

```
- (IBAction)loadURL:(NSURL *)url
{
   // Assume request is a property of our controller
   // First, we'll cancel any in-progress page load
   [[self request] setDelegate:nil];
   [[self request] cancel];

   [self setRequest:[ASIWebPageRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   [[self request] setDelegate:self];
   [[self request] setDidFailSelector:@selector(webPageFetchFailed:)];
   [[self request] setDidFinishSelector:@selector(webPageFetchSucceeded:)];

   // Tell the request to embed external resources directly in the page
   [[self request] setUrlReplacementMode:ASIReplaceExternalResourcesWithData];

   // It is strongly recommended you use a download cache with ASIWebPageRequest
   // When using a cache, external resources are automatically stored in the cache
   // and can be pulled from the cache on subsequent page loads
   [[self request] setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];

   // Ask the download cache for a place to store the cached data
   // This is the most efficient way for an ASIWebPageRequest to store a web page
   [[self request] setDownloadDestinationPath:
      [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToStoreCachedResponseDataForRequest:[self request]]];

   [[self request] startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)webPageFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
   // Obviously you should handle the error properly...
   NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest error]);
}

- (void)webPageFetchSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
   NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
      [theRequest downloadDestinationPath] encoding:[theRequest responseEncoding] error:nil];
   // Note we're setting the baseURL to the url of the page we downloaded. This is important!
   [webView loadHTMLString:response baseURL:[request url]];
}
```