# Store HTML with associated CSS and JS file from UIWebView for offline purpose in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

Currently in my app I am loading html page in UIWebView using loadRequest method of it.

This HTML includes number of js and css files. Now I need to store this HTML page with necessary js and css files. After page is loaded I need to give option to user whether user wants to store it for offline viewing or not.

I tried a lot but I couldn't store js or css file.

I have seen other post( [How to save a locally loaded HTML file in UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535104/how-to-save-a-locally-loaded-html-file-in-uiwebview) ) to save html loaded in UIWebView but couldn't find anything about js and css file.

Let me know whether it is possible or not and if yes then how.

Comment: Have you tried looking at doing this with a cache manifest file?http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ some more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540240/html5-cache-manifest-in-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ASIHTTPRequest. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165973/save-html-page-with-the-images-javascript-and-css-in-one-folder-in-iphone-applic), it has a nice description of this process.

Hope this helps.. :)